# A Circular Riddle

Tags: riddle, pattern, rhyme, steganography

> Circular as this puzzle may not look
>   Devilish forces have already found the book
>   Heavens, of course, would never stay still
>   If only it were easy, they would have got the seal
>
> North is where the enemies always hide
>   Why is The Almighty always right?
>   You cannot complain, you cannot escape
>   Even if it cannot divide the magic shape
>
> Joy will increase, and suffering will eradicate
>   Mastering chronobarbology is to change the Fate
>   Rendering everything above as nothing but rubbish
>   Zoom now, with great victory shall you finish
>
> It has been told, glory comes first from the Chinese
>   Prophecy says it originates in India or Greece
>   You really need not suspect the entire being
>   Because the crucial part lies in one silver lining
>
> Do not worry, stanzas are only for beauty
>   Go for where you start from, and you will see
>   On the surface is this riddle nonsensical
>   So what is needed is outrageously numerical

Hint:

> This poem might look bad but it's difficult to make it better while maintaining the *constrained writing* .

Comment: Are the minor grammar mistakes of "forces has" and "stanzas is" intentional?

Comment: @LukeBickell Oops, sorry. They aren't. Thanks for pointing out the mistake! I'm not a native English speaker, btw.

Comment: @Nathanael I saw that you were from Indonesia so I thought that might be the case :)

Comment: Love the reference to chronobarbology here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, long time lurker, but finally found an unsolved puzzle that I figured out the answer to in order to create an account. :P

> As @DavidFoong mentioned, the answer is indeed pi. The steganography
>  in the puzzle relates to the first letter of each line and its
>  corresponding A1Z26 number. Each digit of pi adds its value to the
>  previous letter to make the next letter, i.e.:
>
>  C = 3
>  D = 3+1
>  H = 3+1+4
>  I = 3+1+4+1
>  N = 3+1+4+1+5
>  W = 3+1+4+1+5+9
>  Y = 3+1+4+1+5+9+2
>  E = 3+1+4+1+5+9+2+6 (Looping back around from Z26 to A1)
>  ...
>  S = 3+1+4+1+5+9+2+6+5+3+5+8+9+7+9+3+2+3+8+4+6
>
>  Which when removing the + signs (and adding a period) gives us
>  3.14159265358979323846, the (approximate) value of pi!

Along with this, the puzzle also includes several side clues to lead us to the answer. @DavidFoong has most of the side clues solved, so check out his answer for those. The couple that he missed are:

Even if it cannot divide the magic shape

> Due to pi being an irrational number, it cannot be divided by a division sign (e.g. 22/7, where 22 and 7 are *divided* by /).

Do not worry, stanzas are only for beauty
Go for where you start from, and you will see

> The text is (mostly) filler, with some hints mixed in. Where you're starting from is the start of the sentence.

You really need not suspect the entire being
Because the crucial part lies in one silver lining

> This refers to the block of text itself, i.e. you don't need to read all the text, just the letters that lie along the line on the left made by the blockquote.

Comment: You got the correct answer! I prefer yours rather than @DavidFoong 's answer because this is the main puzzle, while Foong's is just the side clues.

Comment: Awesome! Are there any particular side clues you want to add to the answer to make it 'complete'? I'll accept any edits/additions you want to make, unless you think there are some side clues that haven't been solved yet.

Comment: The last two lines of the fourth stanza suggests that the answer lies on a line (do you see it?) and the "Go for where you start from" means it's the starting letter. And, "cannot divide" suggests irrationality. By the way, welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: Updated. Let me know if I've misunderstood anything!

Comment: Also thanks! Probably won't post too often, since it's rare that I have an answer to an unsolved question. :P I'd say that's a good indication of the quality of your puzzle!

Comment: You're welcome! As a new member too, I am really amazed by your formatting skills (new members don't know how to put spoilers usually!) And to be honest, I myself don't answer quite often either, and if you see my profile, the ratio of questions to answers are ridiculous. So, if you feel that you like riddles but you can't solve one, then make one!  (PS People around here generally prefer one long comment compared to a few short ones, and FYI, comments can be edited.)

Comment: Hmm... I can only see the delete buttons on my comments, but there's probably something super obvious I'm missing haha (edit: I can see the edit button on this comment, but not older ones. Time limit on edits perhaps.). And yeah, getting the spoilers to work was a major pain to figure out (that was a puzzle in itself), especially since I'm used to a forum using BBCode where I can just enclose everything in spoiler tags. I've got a couple of visual puzzles that I'm making in preparation for a game on my home forum, so maybe I'll test them out here sometime!

Comment: Nice answer. And I thought I was onto something when I found a cigar in the fourth stanza. Ha!

Answer (score 5):

Wild guess, but is it:

> pi

I got lost somewhere along the line, but there are a few reasons I think this might be the answer.

Circular as this puzzle may not look

> referring to a circle. Went ahead and drew one

North is where the enemies always hide

> put a point at the top of the circle. I should note, this ended up pointing me nowhere

Why is The Almighty always right?

> put a point on the right. (draw a right triangle)? Not really sure what to do with this, but it got me thinking about pi

Rendering everything above as nothing but rubbish

> the religious hints mean nothing. This could also be another instruction on what to do in the circle.

It has been told, glory comes first from the Chinese
Prophecy says it originates in India or Greece

> pi was approximated in several different countries. The first was most likely China. Later on, India and Greece used different methods to approximate it.

On the surface is this riddle nonsensical

> another line about how some of the text mean nothing

So what is needed is outrageously numerical

> the answer is a number

Comment: Correct answer! It is indeed pi. However, I won't accept you figure out the main steganography needed to get pi. PS: The North thing and Almighty thing isn't meant to be taken literally, or meaningfully. And there is no need to make a circle.

Comment: @WilliamNathanael Sweet! I'll take a crack at it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> 0

Why:
*Even if it cannot divide the magic shape*

> Cannot be divided

*It has been told, glory comes first from the Chinese

Prophecy says it originates in India or Greece*

> Zero originates from Mesopotamia, went to the Indians, then to the Greeks and Chinese gave it it's circular shape.

*On the surface is this riddle nonsensical

So what is needed is outrageously numerical*

> Don't try to make sense of the words, look for something numerical

Circular riddle

> 0 has a circular shape

Comment: can't understand this "The number of letters before the word"?? Can you explain it bit more.

Comment: @Anurag I edited it, I meant counting the number of letters

Comment: But from Circular to Fate, there are 413 characters only in riddle. Not sure if this is the correct answer.

Comment: Good try, but not the correct answer. Zero is, to some extent, a bit boring. I think this requires a bit of simple steganography.